# Responsive menu: go to URL on second click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive menu on my site
I want to show menu dropdown on first click and on second click the menu tab goes to URL

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/khizer_najeeb/7rRK7

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-principal">
  <li><a href="#" class="one">Zero</a></li>
  <li><a href="one.html" class="two">One</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="one1.html" class="one1">One 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="one1.html" class="one2">One 2</a>
         <ul><li><a href="one1.html" class="one2">One 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="one1.html" class="one2">One 2</a></li></ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="one1.html" class="one3">One 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="two.html" class="two">Two</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="two1" class="two1">Two 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="two2" class="two2">Two 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="two3" class="two3">Two 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#menu-principal { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px; list-style: none; }
ul#menu-principal li { border-bottom: 1px solid #164a7f; }
ul#menu-principal li li:last-child { width: 85px; border-bottom: none; }       
ul#menu-principal li a {  display: block; height: 28px;  background: #FFF; }
ul#menu-principal ul{padding:0 0 0 30px; width: 150px}
ul#menu-principal li li {  }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-principal li').children('ul').hide();
    $('#menu-principal li').click(function () {

        if ($(this).children('ul').is('') == true) {
            return false
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: you question is not clear....you dont want to redirect when class `TWO` is clicked, instead, drop down should open ???

Comment: When click on the parent menu dropdown will open and than second time I click on the parent menu it will go to the selective URL OR any other page

Comment: Use prevent default to make it -not- follow link on first click. If the children are visible you simply don't prevent the link action.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/7rRK7/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this code :**

```
if ($(this).children('ul').is('') == true) {
         return false
}
```

**To below code:**

```
if ($(this).children('ul,p').is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).children('ul,p').slideDown('slow');
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Replace following code:**

```
$('#menu-principal li').click(function () {

    if ($(this).children('ul').is('') == true) {
        return false
    }
})
```

**With following**

```
$('#menu-principal a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().children('ul').is(':visible') != true) {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This was really helpful, but I found a bug as the code applies to all links within the parent navigation, including the links inside the child ul, so, change this line:

```
$('#menu-principal a').click(function () {
```

To this:

```
$('#menu-principal a').not('ul ul a').click(function (e) {
```